# Get tow column from nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

Using the following code I am getting the max value

```
select
  max(e.maxNum)
from (select
    companyno as cn,
    count(employeeNo) as maxNum
      from works
      group by companyNo) e;
```

But i also need the "companyNo" like (companyno, e.maxNum)

I tried

```
select
  e.cn,
  max(e.maxNum)
from (select
    companyno as cn,
    count(employeeNo) as maxNum
      from works
      group by companyNo) e;
```

but i am getting error

How to solve this?

table format

```
works(employeeNo, companyNo, salary)
company(companyNo, companyName, city)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  max(CompanyNo) keep (dense_rank first order by count(employeeNo) desc) as cn,
  max(count(employeeNo)) maxNum
from Works
group by CompanyNo
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c7fe/1)

Comment: can u please explain the "keep" and "dense_rank" keyword? these are new to me.